# Style for blinking div

Tags: css

I have a div which I need to blink twice every 5 minutes if a certain checkbox is checked. I managed to do it to blink twice but I have trouble with the interval. This is my code:

```
<div class="my-status" [ngClass]="isChecked ? 'enabled-status' : 'disabled-status'"></div>

.enabled-status{
  background: $secondary;
  animation: blinker 1s linear 2;
}

.disabled-status{
  background: $gray;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

How do I do this to repeat every 5 minutes if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: by adding a timer for 5 minutes and then add a class for starting the blinking?

Comment: Can you share the compiled HTML and CSS please? Are you open to using JavaScript, or does this need to be CSS only? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<div>` below will blink twice every 10 seconds.

To make it blink twice every 5 minutes, we need to:

- change `10s` to `300s`
- change `1%`, `2%`, `3%`, `4%` into something like `0.1%`, `0.2%`, `0.3%`, `0.4%`

**Working Example:**

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  1%, 3% {opacity: 0;}
  2%, 4% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="square blink"></div>
```

Comment: Why not just make the animation timer 300s to begin with?

Comment: Hah! Because I was working on the basis that visitors to this page might want to see a working example which didn't take up an entire third of their coffee break. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.enabled-status{
      background: $secondary;
      animation: blinker 300s linear infinite;
    }
    
    .disabled-status{
      background: $gray;
    }
    
    @keyframes blinker {
      50% { opacity: 0; }
    }
```